# how to check if user has role or permission in blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laratrust

I am working with Laravel 8 and I use Laratrust package for roles and permissions

i Use the following directives to check role or permission in blade view

```
@permission('add_user')
<a href="route({{'add_user')}}">create new user </a>
@endpermission

@role('admin')
<a href="route({{'add_user')}}">create new user </a>
@endrole
```

my question is there any way to check both role and permission at the same time

some thing like

> @role('admin') || @permission('add_user')

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the user has permission in the view:

```
$user->hasRole(['owner', 'admin']);  // this returns true
```

Or by the logged user:

```
Auth::user()->hasRole('role-name');
```

Or this:

```
Auth::user()->hasPermission('permission-name');
```

Answer (score 0):

for this kind of job we have gate in laravel you can simply register a gate inside AuthServiceProvider.php

```
Gate::define('owner',function(User $user){
   if($user->hasRole == "owner" && $user->hasPermission == "permission-name"){
       return true;
   }
   return false;
})
```

then inside blade you can check using @can operator

```
@can('owner')
   "write something which visible to owner"
@endcan
```

note don't forget to import Gate facades inside provider

Comment: if you have n no of permission then you can go with policies in laravel